# Insert into a table multiple variables using dynamic query

Tags: sql, dynamic

I'm trying to use an interim dynamic query to insert data into a table variable and then use that table variable to execute a final query. I have an error "must declare scalar variable "

```
DECLARE @t TABLE ( TableName NVARCHAR(250) )
declare @i as int = 1,  @A_1 NVARCHAR(250) ='ABC',  @A_2 NVARCHAR(250) ='XYZ', @A_3 NVARCHAR(250) = 'AEI';
WHILE (@i <= 3) 
 BEGIN 
    DECLARE @q NVARCHAR(MAX) = ' DECLARE @t TABLE ( TableName NVARCHAR(250) )
                                insert into @t 
                                select  @A_' + CAST(@i AS VARCHAR) + ' as field
                                from @t
                            '
  INSERT INTO @t
  EXEC(@q)
       SET @i  = @i  + 1

 END
SELECT * FROM @t
```

the expected result should be:

TableName

1. ABC
2. XYZ
3. AEI

variable @A_X could have 1 or 15 variables (@A_1, @A_2....@A15)

Comment: Do you really need to do this as a Dynamic query? Can you change your data model to make it more flexible?  http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html

Comment: It will need to be dynamic as variable @A_X could have multiple values (from 1 to 15)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of table variable you can use temp table. Check this out:

```
DROP TABLE #TableList 
GO
CREATE TABLE #TableList (
         A_1 NVARCHAR(250)
        ,A_2 NVARCHAR(250)
        ,A_3 NVARCHAR(250)
)

DROP TABLE #Result 
GO
CREATE TABLE #Result (
         TableName  NVARCHAR(250)
)

INSERT INTO #TableList
VALUES('ABC','XYZ','AEI')

DECLARE @q NVARCHAR(MAX)='';
DECLARE   @i as int = 1

WHILE (@i <= 3) 
BEGIN 
    SET  @q   = @q+CHAR(13)+' 
                    INSERT INTO #Result(TableName)
                    SELECT  A_' + CAST(@i AS VARCHAR) + ' from #TableList;'

    SET @i = @i + 1
END

EXEC sp_executesql @q
PRINT (@q)

SELECT *
FROM #Result
```